# Getting int value from oracle to_date

Tags: php, oracle

I have a problem in my programming assignment. So I need to pull `INT` value so I can do further processing. My current code is:

```
$totalRemDaysSql = "select to_date(due_date) - trunc(sysdate) as remdays from project where project_name = :projName";
$totalRemDaysParse = oci_parse($conn, $totalRemDaysSql);
oci_bind_by_name($totalRemDaysParse, ":projName", $_SESSION['cd-dropdown']);         
oci_define_by_name($totalRemDaysParse, "REMDAYS", $remainingDays);
```

When I do `var_dump($remainingDays)`, the value is string.

My question is how do I get the INT value out of `$remainingDays`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @mudasobwa I tried that but still doesn't work.

`<?php while(oci_fetch($totalRemDaysParse)){$remainingDays;}
$intRemainingDays = intval($remainingDays); ?>

<?php var_dump($remainingDays); ?>`

Comment: You're using `TO_DATE()` without an [explicit format mask](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php).

Comment: What datatype is `due_date`? The name sounds like a `DATE`, then the function `to_date` would be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Try

to_date(due_date,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') - to_date(sysdate,'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') as remdays

(format mask is just an example)